# Command Tab to show a 'hidden' app

Tags: macos

With Command W you 'hide' most of the apps excluding the ones with tabs.

But then when you do Command Tab, the hidden app doesn't show up.

How come?
How do you quickly bring back focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> doesn’t hide the apps; it closes the current active window. That's why you can't show them up using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, because the window is no longer exist.

You can hide application using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This shortcut won’t close the window, so you can bring all the hidden windows of a application back by using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and selecting the application.